# Prove $ne^{-n}$ converges to zero

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How would I prove that $ne^{-n}$ converges to zero? I've tried $ne^{-n}<{\epsilon}$ and then logging both sides but no further progress could be made.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Hint***

$$ 0 \le \frac{n}{e^n} \le \frac{2^n}{e^n} = \left({\frac{2}{e}} \right)^n  $$

We know that $ e \gt 2$ and hence the geometric series $\sum  \left({\frac{2}{e}} \right)^n$ converges which necessitates that $ \lim  \left({\frac{2}{e}} \right)^n = 0$.  Now we apply the Squeeze Theorem.

---

You can use your approach too.

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be arbitrary.

$$ \left|{\frac{n}{e^n}}\right|  =  \frac{n}{e^n} \le \frac{2^n}{e^n}  $$

Now, notice that $ \dfrac{2^n}{e^n} \lt \epsilon \iff \ln {\dfrac{2^n}{e^n}} \lt \ln \epsilon \iff n \ln \dfrac{2}{e}  \lt \ln \epsilon \iff n \gt \dfrac{\ln \epsilon}{\ln \dfrac{2}{e}  } $

where $\ln \dfrac{2}{e} \lt 0 $ since $ \dfrac{2}{e} \lt 1$

Comment: Your first inequality is wrong. You can simply replace $\frac1n$ by $0$.

Comment: @Sami Ben Romdhane: You're right. Edited.

Comment: @Ishfaaq Thanks. How would you modify the first approach to show that $ne^{-an}$ tends to 0 where $a>0$?

Comment: ... Why not simply note that $e^{an}\geq a^2n^2/2$?

Answer (score 8):

Consider the fact that $e^n\geq n^2/2$. The inequality is a simple consequence of the series expansion of the exponential function.

Comment: so we get that $ne^{-n}{\leq}\frac{2}{n}$?

Comment: Yes, precisely so.

Answer (score 7):

We can use the L'Hôpital's rule to get the result easily:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}xe^{-x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac x{e^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{e^x}=0$$

Comment: Then you still need to show that $e^{-n}$ converges to zero, which is basically the same thing.

Comment: No it isn't the same thing! The desired limit has the indeterminate form $\infty\times 0$ while $e^n$ tends to $\infty$ is a basic result.

Comment: I would argue that $e^n\rightarrow\infty$ is as basic a result as $e^n/n\rightarrow \infty$. I guess it is a matter of taste.

Comment: What's more basic: the fact that $e^n\rightarrow \infty$ or that $e^n>\frac{n^2}2$?

Comment: $e^n>n^2/2$ is a stronger result, but that does not make it any less basic. How would you prove $e^n\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: I remember when I first study this function that we  defined it as the inverse function of the $\ln$ function which is the primitive of $\frac1x$ that vanishes on $1$. We proved that the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$ using the chain rule. We studied the function $e^x-x$ and we proved that $e^x>x$ for all $x\ge0$ so we found that $e^x\to\infty$ at $\infty$. All this are basic for me and at this time we did not even hear about the series.

Comment: The exact same ideas would lead you to consider the function $e^x-x^2/2$ and conclude that $e^x\geq x^2/2$ for all $x\geq 0$. This is what I mean by the result being equally basic, it is just a different way to make use of the same ideas.