# Prove that $\frac{x}{e^x}$ tends to zero as $x \to \infty $

Tags: limits, exponential-function, euler-mascheroni-constant

As the title states, I want to prove 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{e^x} =0$$

Clearly, L'Hopital's rule easily solves this. However, I'm curious to see if there's another way to prove it, without involving some differential or integral calculus (that is, by algebraic means). 
What I'm really interested about, is to prove that 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{e^{x^2}}=0 $$
I assume that proving the first limit will provide a way to prove the second one, using the squeeze method. If you know a direct way to prove the second limit, it will be more than perfect.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: An explicit way to prove it would be via the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit. Given $\epsilon\gt 0$, can you find a $\delta\gt 0$ such that for all $x\gt\delta$, we have $|x/e^x|\lt\epsilon$ ?

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/873373

Comment: @NotAMathematician Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $x>0$, $e^x=1+x+x^2/2+\cdots>x^2/2$ so
$$0<\frac{x}{e^x}<\frac2x.$$
Likewise $e^{x^2}=1+x^2+\cdots>x^2$ so
$$0<\frac{x}{e^{x^2}}<\frac1x.$$

Comment: my preferred way too!

Answer (score 1):

**Mean Value Theorem**

By the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), there is a $\xi\in(x/2,x)$ so that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{e^x-e^{x/2}}{x-x/2}
&=e^{\xi}\\
&\ge e^{x/2}\tag1
\end{align}
$$
However, we also have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{e^x-e^{x/2}}{x-x/2}\le2\,\frac{e^x}{x}
\end{align}\tag2
$$
Putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ together, we get
$$
\frac{x}{e^x}\le2e^{-x/2}\tag3
$$

---

**Bernoulli's Inequality**

[Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) implies that
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac{x}n\right)^n
&\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}n\right)^n\\[6pt]
&=e^x\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{x}{e^x}
&\le\frac{x}{\left(1+\frac{x}2\right)^2}\\[3pt]
&\le\frac4x\tag5
\end{align}
$$

Comment: nice and original way!

Answer (score 0):

For the sequence by ratio test

$$a_n=\frac{n+1}{e^n}\implies \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{n+2}{e^{n+1}}\frac{e^n}{n+1}=\frac{n+2}{n+1}\frac1e\to \frac1e<1\implies \frac{n+1}{e^n}\to 0$$

then observe that for $x\in (n,n+1)$

$$0<\frac{x}{e^x}\le\frac{n+1}{e^n} \to0$$

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to
$\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x}
\to 0$
and this has been proved
many times here,
often by me.

One easy proof:

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(x)
&=\int_1^x \dfrac{dt}{t}\\
&<\int_1^x \dfrac{dt}{t^c}
\qquad\text{where } 0 < c < 1\\
&=\int_1^x t^{-c}dt\\
&=\dfrac{t^{1-c}}{1-c}|_1^x\\
&=\dfrac{x^{1-c}-1}{1-c}\\
&<\dfrac{x^{1-c}}{1-c}\\
\end{array}
$

Now choose $c$ appropriately.
For example,
$c=\frac12$ gives
$\ln(x)
\lt 2x^{1/2}$
so
$\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x}
\lt \dfrac{2}{x^{1/2}}
$.

Setting
$x = e^y$ gives
$\dfrac{y}{e^y}
\lt \dfrac{2}{e^{y/2}}
$.

If $c = 1-d$
where $d$ is small,
this is
$\ln(x)
\lt\dfrac{x^{d}}{d}
$
or
$\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x}
\lt \dfrac1{dx^{1-d}}
$.

In particular,
if $d = 1/n$,
this is
$\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x}
\lt \dfrac{n}{x^{1-1/n}}
$
or
$\dfrac{y}{e^y}
\lt \dfrac{n}{e^{y(1-1/n)}}
$.

Answer (score -1):

First show $$\frac{x}{a^x}\to 0$$ for any $a>1$. This means 
$$\frac{x}{e^{2x}}\to 0$$ and write this as 
$$\frac{x^2}{e^{2x^2}}\to 0$$ now take the square root to get
$$\frac{x}{e^{x^2}}\to 0$$

Comment: If he shows $\frac {x}{a^x}\to 0$ then can't he just substitute $a=e$?