# How to prove that the sequence $x_n= \frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$ is converging

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence $x_n = \frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$. It seems that the sequence tends to $0$ because $\sqrt{n}> \ln(n)$ for all $n$. I need to prove this by definition or otherwise. Can anyone give me some hints helping me proving this?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: it does not tend to zero because $ln(n)< \sqrt n$ !

Comment: Does this inequality say anything about the limit of the sequence?

Comment: Have you heard of L’hopital rule?

Comment: Note that $\ln(n)<n^{1/4}$ for $n>256$, so $0<\ln(n)/\sqrt{n}<\sqrt[4]{n}/\sqrt{n}$ and, by the sandwich theorem, you get that the limit is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x_n=2\dfrac{\log (√n)}{√n}$;

Take the limit.

Recall: $\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\log z}{z}=0.$

$\log z =\displaystyle{\int_{1}^{z}}(1/t)dt<\int_{1}^{z}(1/√t)dt$ =

$(1/2)t^{1/2}\big ]_1^z=$

$(1/2)(z^{1/2}-1) < z^{1/2}.$

Answer (score 1):

For all $x>0$, $\log (1 + x) < x$. Hence, for $n\in \mathbb{N}^+$,
$$
\log n = 4\log \sqrt[4]{n} \le 4(\sqrt[4]{n} - 1) < 4\sqrt[4]{n}.
$$
Consequently
$$
0 \le \frac{{\log n}}{{\sqrt n }} < \frac{4}{{\sqrt[4]{n}}} \to 0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

To prove that $\sqrt n> \ln n$ for $n>4$, consider function $f(x)=\sqrt x - \ln x$. We see that $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{\sqrt x-2}{2x}$. Obviously, $f'(x)>0$ when $\sqrt{x}>2$ so the function is increasing and $f(4)=2-\ln 4>0$.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is to use the fact (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2702749) for a proof)
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{e^x}=0 $$
and consider the sequence $x_n=\ln\left(\sqrt{n}\right)\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.
Hence
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{e^{x_n}}=\frac 12\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt n}=0$$