# Prove the following sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am fairly confident that if $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ is such that $0<\alpha<1$, then the sequence
$$(a_n):a_n=n\alpha^n$$
converges to $0$. I created a generalization of a method found in [Prove $ne^{-n}$ converges to zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873373/prove-ne-n-converges-to-zero/873378) for $0<\alpha<1/2$ in which you argue
$$n\alpha^n\leq \left(\frac{2}{(1/\alpha)}\right)^n$$
and use results about geometric series, but I am completely lost on the formal proof for $1/2<\alpha <1$. Maybe a hint to help me get started?

Alternatively, if such a hint/solution is overly complicated, I would greatly appreciate a simpler solution (if it exists) that can at least show the sequence is bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^{nt} \geq \frac {n^{2}t^{2}} 2$ for $t \geq 0$. Put $t =-\ln \alpha$. You get $\alpha^{-n} \geq cn^{2}$ for some $c>0$. Can you finish?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you are getting the fact that if $t>0$, then $e^{nt}\geq \frac{n^2t^2}{2}$  from the taylor series expansion of $e^x$?

Comment: @northcity4 Exactly.

Comment: Just saw your edit, that explains a lot.

Comment: @northcity4 There was a typo. I meant to take $t=- ln \alpha$

Comment: Ok I think I got it. Given $\alpha$, we have shown that for all $n\geq 1$ that $n\alpha^n\leq 1/(nc)$. From here we can use something like a comparison test for sequences (such as the squeeze theorem with the $0$-sequence and the sequence $(1/nc)$). Is this correct?

Comment: @northcity4 Yes, you are right.

Comment: I should note for others seeing this post that the solution can be derived using the ratio test (only saw this later on).